# How to convert a character to an HTML Entities using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example:
`convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana")` should return `Dolce &amp; Gabbana`

Comment: the cheating way .... create a HTMLElement like a span or div etc ... add the text as innerText ... retrieve it from innerHTML